# Apache2, basic/digest authentication gives Password Mismatch

Tags: git, apache, authentication, apache2, ubuntu-16.04

I configured git over https (apache2.4.18) on my Ubuntu 16.04 server. It is possible to git clone and git push origin master. This works correctly. I now only struggle with a nasty error line in the apache logging. I already tried the answer of nick-m in [Apache 2.4 "..authentication failure..:Password Mismatch"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751242/apache-2-4-authentication-failure-password-mismatch) 
But this seems not to work in my setup.

With Basic Authentication

```
[Fri Jan 05 22:30:36.005096 2018] [auth_basic:error] [pid 26528] [client xx.yy.zz.127:47840] AH01617: user blabla: authentication failure for "/git/test12/info/refs": Password Mismatch
```

With Digest Authentication

```
[Fri Jan 05 22:20:24.908593 2018] [auth_digest:error] [pid 25748] [client xx.yy.zz.127:47528] AH01794: user blabla: password mismatch: /git/test12/info/refs
```

It seems that there are more people struggling with this strange htpasswd/htdigest apache2 behaviour. Now my git commands are working, but I don't like the error messages in the logging :) Perhaps someone out-there has another suggestion. For some projects I use git over ssh, but from some locations I like to use the https variant.

[Gerrit clone using http behind a apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47071484/gerrit-clone-using-http-behind-a-apache2)

[Git over HTTP generates authentication failure in Apache error_log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133678/git-over-http-generates-authentication-failure-in-apache-error-log)

Comment: I reported this bug to git developers, I tried to investigate this again and found out that git client makes additional GET request which causes this error.

Comment: Thank you very much! Regards, Jan